# Should I perform table optimization on MySql InnoDB tables?

Tags: mysql, optimization, mariadb

I have MySQL (actually - MariaDB) database with some InnoDB tables.
Records in such tables are never deleting, only inserting and updating.
Number of records are already relatively big - around few millions.
These tables, I believe, have never been optimized since creation.

Should I optimize such tables?
How to verify if I should optimize such tables?

Comment: Simple Rule of Thumb:  Never use `OPTIMIZE TABLE` on an InnoDB table.

Comment: Why? Bill Karwin below suggests opposite, and he explains why... Seems like there is some contradicting points of view, that is why i am asking...

Comment: Bill is addressing your _stated_ question -- "When should I OPTIMIZE?".  I am addressing the _implied_ question -- "Should I OPTIMIZE?".  I agree that when you do a big `DELETE`, `OPTIMIZE` _may_ be desirable.  However, for a "big delete" there may be a way to _avoid_ the fragmentation.  (This is a long discussion that I have tackled in other Questions.)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there is nearly no way to tell if you need to optimize an InnoDB table.

As you delete or update rows (I know you said you don't delete), it can leave gaps where the old version of a row was. Optimizing a table copies all the rows to a new table, with no gaps, so it accomplished "defragmentation" and probably stores the table more compactly.

You can run `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tablename'\G` and get a report that shows the size of the gaps. It's reported as the column `data_free` in that status result. But here's the thing: `data_free` only includes gaps of 1MB or larger. Smaller gaps are not counted, and these might end up accounting for a lot of fragmentation. There's literally no way to report the total of the small gaps.

So should you optimize such tables? Maybe! It wouldn't be a bad thing to do it, say once a month.

But doesn't it lock the table and block queries while you optimize? Yes, sort of. That's why I use [pt-online-schema-change](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-online-schema-change.html) to run a no-op change (use the `--alter=force` option), so it can be done any time, without blocking clients.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have tried to play on some smaller test tables first, and I see data_free is still 4194304, even immediately after run optimize on that table. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes, probably. When tablespaces grow, they are increased by 4MB at a time. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-space.html Those 4MB will be filled as you insert new rows of data, then the tablespace will be expanded again when needed.

Comment: @SergeS - InnoDB keeps 4M to 7M preallocated for each table.  (_Or each partition of a table!_)  You can't 'eliminate' that `Data_free`.  And there are _many_ other parts of the file that are "free" but not mentioned or tallied.